Does IntelliJ Ultimate allow to generate a package diagram for a selected directory?
I'm trying to figure out if and how to generate a package diagram for a project in IntelliJ IDEA, but so far I don't understand if there is any way to generate it at all
What I've tried: Of the diagram options, I've only explored and found that you can generate a class diagram via right-click. But this is a class diagram, not a package diagram

Actually there is no real difference in these diagram types. The UML spec explicitly allows to use (almost) anything in (almost) any diagram type. So you can use a class diagram to just show packages, if you like.

From the documentation:
View diagram on a package﻿
"In the Project tool window, right-click a package for which you want to create a diagram and select Diagrams | Show Diagram
(⌘Сmd ⌥Option ⇧Shift U on macOS).
In the list that opens, select Java Class Diagram. IntelliJ IDEA generates a UML diagram for classes and their dependencies."
If your project contains multiple modules, you can create a project module diagram. Select a module, right-click to open the context menu, select Diagrams | Show Diagrams and select Project Modules.
Afaik there is no UML package diagram.

Currently the Diagrams plugin in the IntelliJ IDEA supports the following chart types:

UML Class diagrams
IDEA Module dependencies diagrams

Unfortunately it currently does not support package diagram.
